# Error with Basic Rcpp List Input

Tags: c++, list, input, rcpp, unordered-map

I am unable to figure out what is causing an error in the following code. Briefly, the code tries to loop over list elements (each of which is a vector of integers), and assign them to a map data structure in order.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void getPathsFromList(Rcpp::List& pathsList,
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> >& paths ){

  Rcpp::List plist(pathsList);
  int p=plist.size();
  for( int i=0;i<p; i++ ){
      SEXP e = plist[i];
      Rcpp::NumericVector v(e);
      for( int j=0; j<v.size(); j++ ){
          paths[i].push_back( v[j] );
      }
   }

 }
```

The error I get is the following:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::unordered_map<int, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::hash<int>, std::__1::equal_to<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > > >
```

I also tried explicitly assigning `v[j]` above to an `int` variable and then pushing it into the vector, but did not quite help. It appears that I am missing something fundamental and I would greatly appreciate any help. (I am on OSX Mavericks.)

Comment: Please add some sample data that you expect to make the call with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately, *no* support in *Rcpp* to work with a `std:map<int, vector<int> >`. Thus, the "import" call or bringing R objects into C++ is unable to be formed.

If you were to remove the `// [[Rcpp::export]]` and simply call it via C++ and then reformat the object in C++ call to `Rcpp::List` out, then all would be okay.

Also, you do need to declare the C++11 flag since `unordered_map` is C++11 specific via:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
```

e.g.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

void getPathsFromList(Rcpp::List& pathsList,
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> >& paths ){

  Rcpp::List plist(pathsList);
  int p=plist.size();
  for( int i=0;i<p; i++ ){
      SEXP e = plist[i];
      Rcpp::NumericVector v(e);
      for( int j=0; j<v.size(); j++ ){
          paths[i].push_back( v[j] );
      }
   }

 }
```